# Error: Application installation failed (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

No puedo correr mi aplicacion de Android Studio en mi celular. Me sale un error referente a "Application installation failed".
El error completo es el siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas en [es.so], favor de traducir la pregunta.

Comment: Mil disculpas :( jaja Ya lo traduci :)

Comment: Creo que te falta el permiso *INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL*. No sé lo que es pero por el error... Pon el permiso en el manifest y a ver qué pasa.

Answer (score 0):

El código de tu aplicación requiere el permiso:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

**el problema aquí es que tu aplicación debe ser definida como una aplicación del sistema**

revisa :

[CÓMO CONVERTIR UNA APLICACIÓN DE ANDROID EN UNA APLICACIÓN DEL SISTEMA](https://www.movilzona.es/tutoriales/android/root/como-convertir-una-aplicacion-de-android-en-una-aplicacion-del-sistema/)